# Set custom tab in customer edit page Active

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, adminhtml, tabs

I created a custom tab for customer edit page in backend like this:

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
             <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Vcard" name="customer_edit_tab_vcard" >
              <action method="setTabLabel">
                  <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">V-Card</argument>
              </action>
            </block>
          </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

When i opened the customer edit page, the first tab that is active is **Customer View**

[image: example]

How can i set my custom tab that is active?

Comment: Do you mean you want set your custom tab as active by default when you edit any customer?

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes, to be precise i'll add get param to the url , when this get param exist in the url , my custom tab will be active

Comment: So when you will get param from url then only your tab will show active. Is it correct?

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes that is correct , for example http://mage2.loc/admin/customer/index/edit/id/118/vcard/1/key/348e230d982jac35dfaa73c888b62f49f34b812090cb4h3n28f2a1ce7d52495 , the param will be vcard

Comment: @blue have u got a solution for this ?

Comment: @chris i ended up using jquery to click the tab when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 backend forms, by default, the active tab is set based on which module loads first in the sequence.

If you check **addTab** method in **Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface\Tab** class you will see that logic setup first added tab to active status if the active tab does not determine.

Comment: so how can i set my tab to be active?